# how to wire GFCI and dual light switch

Tags: wiring

]My mother live in an older house and has two regular light switches in bathroom.   one for light and other for exhaust for the exhaust fan

[image]

I would like to add an GFCI outlet in place of one of the switches and move both switches to one side.

The parts Im thiking of using are:
[15 Amp, 120/277 Volt, Decora Single-Pole / Single-Pole AC Combination Switch, Commercial Grade, Grounding, Side Wired - Brown](https://www.leviton.com/en/products/5634)

[15 Amp, 125 Volt Dual Function AFCI/GFCI Receptacle, 20 Amp Feed-Through, Tamper-Resistant, Monochromatic, back and side wired, nylon wallplate/faceplate, screws and self-grounding clip included – Brown](https://www.leviton.com/en/products/agtr1)

I would like the light switch to be independent of the outlet and fan switch

Im thinking of connecting the Fan switch to the load of the outlet.

Using my diagram, can someone please tell me how to correctly wire all this together? ex Light switch= LH>7 and LL>5  etc.

[image]

any help is appreciated.

P.S. As this is an older house, Im pretty sure there is no ground wire and the gangbox is metal.

P.S.S here requested pictures of inside of box
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure there's a Neutral wire in the box? Just because a wire is white doesn't mean it's neutral. Pull the switches out and show us a pic of how they're wired.

Comment: The first thing is easy: Don't use the GFCI LOAD terminals.  The GFCI will come with warning tape across the "Load" terminals; *leave it there* -- 90% of your potential problems will come from trying to use it, and there's no earthly reason to use it.  "I don't know where else to put the wires" -> we will educate you.

Comment: @Harper, is it not common to protect an exhaust fan with GFCI?  I know I've seen it done, but I have no idea if its "proper" or not.

Comment: AFIK it only makes sense to GF protect a receptacle which will be used for appliances you can touch in normal use. I see no reason to go out of your way to GF protect a ceiling exhaust fan or ceiling lights. Our two bathrooms (1970 build) are protected by a GFCI breaker and are wired on one circuit. So far no GF trips from exhaust fans, but if it did happen, then we would lose all lights and receptacles (one in each bathroom). Who needs that on some busy morning?

Comment: The outlet is right next to the bathroom vanity sink.  I just want want to be safe in case she drops her curing iron etc into the sink

Comment: A lot of hair dryers have a GFCI in their plug. Do your wife's appliances have that? You would still want GFCI protection for any receptacle close to the sink and I think code requires it for any receptacle in the bathroom, but it's not necessary for the fan and overhead light. What is the location in the bathroom of this 2-gang box? Do you have a receptacle in the bathroom already?

Comment: Do you have a receptacle already (by the sink), but you want another one and wish to place it in the box with the switches?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Protecting everything with GFCI "out of an abundance of caution" is a great plan up until you start getting nuisance trips. Then the non-expert is likely to rip the GFCI off the wall and you have nothing at all.

Comment: @Harper, right, I wasn't being argumentative or saying it _should_ be protected.  I just really didn't know if it was common, accepted practice.  You can't touch the fan, so it doesn't seem like it needs it, but it wouldn't be the first code item to err on the side of caution (if it was code).

Comment: You haven't got an answer yet because we are waiting for you.  We need to see what is inside the switch box and how the switches are currently connected. This is mandatory to be able to give  you an answer.

Comment: The fan is really irrelevant.  I'm just trying to add an outlet to where there was none before.  right not theres only two sources of power in the gangbox.  one for each switch.  I just figured I could use the fans hot line to power the outlet and fan

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box with the switches unscrewed but not unwired? (Turn the breaker for this bathroom off before doing that, of course)

Comment: thanx.  I will post pictures shortly.

Comment: @JimStewart , no all there is there is two light switched like the picture shows

Comment: Did you say there are *two* power sources here?  Do  you have to turn off 2 breakers to get both the fan and the light to completely shut off?  (that's not unusual, I just want to confirm it).

Comment: actually yes.  I had to turn off two breakers when taking this picture

Comment: Were either of them 20A breakers? Did other things turn off when you turned them off?

Comment: looks like they are all 15A breakers

Comment: and yes, other things turned off in different rooms when the breaker was shut off